# Integrating external JS libraries in Ember

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple application that uses jqplot to graph data.  This application has a single route attached to an ArrayController.  I display the items to be graphed on the left side using the {{#each}} helper; I also display a 'graph' button up top.  The user can select one or more entries from the list and hit the graph button.  The button is attached to an action that calls jqplot to graph the selected data on the right side.  Functionally, this works fine, but feels like a hack.  Does anyone have an opinion on how this can be re-structured to perform similar function the 'Ember way'?

This app only has one model, so doesn't seem like I would need a second route.  I do need to somehow handle re-graphing if the user resizes the window. If I weren't using Ember, I would handle window resizing like this:

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    plot1.replot ({resetAxes: true});
 });
```

where 'plot1' is the return value from the original call to jqplot.

How do I do this in Ember?

I'm using Ember 1.4 with EmberData beta 7.

Answer (score 0):

You can put custom JS code in the `didInsertElement()` hook of your view, which will be executed after the view is rendered.

There's a corresponding `willDestroyElement()` hook for your teardown code.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  I'm not sure what I would put in here.